# How to make the hbs module of node.js retrieve info in HTML instead of plain text?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, handlebars.js, node-modules

I have a handlebars file (**index.hbs**) who is receiving some data from my **server.js** like this:

```
{{#each person}}
   {{name}}
   {{bio}}
{{/each}}
```

But the **{{bio}}** is populated with some HTML data, like:

```
Hello this is my <b>bio</b> and has HTML on it.
```

How can I make it HTML? So for example the b tag shows as bold and not as HTML tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found it! Just add one more pair of curly braces. Like this:

```
{{{bio}}}
```